# How to patch two function calls when they are called together in python

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest, python-mock

I have a function which uses below code.

```
def get_doc_hash(doc):
       return hashlib.md5(doc.encode(‘utf-8’)).hexdigest()
```

How can I mock both the calls of md5() and hexdigest() to write test cases for this function ?

Comment: That doesn't sound like you need to mock anything at all. You can just test that.

Comment: I can test the string return type but I just want to find out how can I mock them to find that the calls to md5 and hexdigest were made.

Comment: But what matters is the behavior, not the implementation. You should test that the function produces correct hashes, not that it uses one particular hashing library in one particular way.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I agree that I can calculate the hash and call the test function and then do the assertion. But just want to know how this can be done. Patching the two function calls when they are called together.

Comment: May be trivial to test in this case, but from my pov, it is a valid strategy to mock out any 3rd party calls as we are not testing them - only testing that they are called appropriately

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica im guessing that you have down voted the answer? If this is the case could you please justify why? It does what the OP asked for and as i've said in the comment above - this can be a valid testing strategy even if it is trivial in this case. Constructive criticism would be appreciated also

Comment: @MilosMatovic: Well, I hadn't downvoted it before, but I have now. You seem to have attempted to fix the OP's broken code, but your attempt failed - your `get_doc_hash` doesn't make sense either. `hexdigest` is a method of the hasher object returned by `hashlib.md5`, not a method of the bytestring returned by `encode`.

Comment: A behavior test would have caught that bug, but since you instead tested for the calls you expected to happen, your test missed it. This demonstrates the importance of testing that code behaves properly instead of testing that it has the implementation you expect it to have.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica thanks, i wasn't aware of that as the syntax is not right in the OP code. I will adapt the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in comments, it would be better to test for expected behaviour, but purely for purpose of showing how to chain mocks, here is how it can be done:

```
import hashlib
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch


def get_doc_hash(doc):
    return hashlib.md5(doc.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()


class TestHash(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('hashlib.md5')
    def test_get_doc_hash_to_demonstrate_mock_chaining(self, mock_hashlib):
        mock_hashlib.return_value.hexdigest.return_value = "digested"
        hash_out = get_doc_hash("test doc")
        mock_hashlib.assert_called_once_with("test doc".encode("utf-8"))
        mock_hashlib.return_value.hexdigest.assert_called_once()
        self.assertEqual(hash_out, "digested")
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I’m learning to add test cases and wanted to find this paradigm even though it doesn’t make sense here. It helps me. I see the comments trail in question. The typo got added as I had asked the question on phone. I have edited the code to correct it.